# Question about Jordan form - Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Quick question,

We are given that the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$ is $P_A(x)=(x-1)^4$

We are asked to find all the possible jordan forms of $A$.

Obviously the minimal polynomial of $A$ can be $m_A(x)=(x-1)^k$, $ 1 \leq k \leq 4$

I understand that the size of the largest block in the jordan form is $k$, because The exponent of the term corresponding to an eigenvalue in the minimal polynomial is the size of the largest block.

But there is also a thing we can say about the characteristic polynomial, but I don't understand it.

We know that **"The algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue is the sum of the total sizes of the blocks."** Could someone please explain and demonstrate what this means?

Comment: That means that for each eigenvalue $\;\lambda\;$, the total sum of the blocks' lengths will be $\;k\;$ when $\;(x-\lambda)^k\;$ divides the char. pol. but $\;(x-\lambda)^{k+1}\;$ doesn't. In your present case,  the sum of these blocks is four... **but** ...it isn't true that four is the size of the largest Jordan Block (=JB), but the *maximal* size a JB can attain!

Comment: and if i told you that the minimal polynomial is also $(x-1)^4$ then would we be able to say that the matrix has a jordan block sized 4?

Comment: Of course, @Oria : there is no choice there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possibilities are

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\;\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\;\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

and the corresponding minimal pol. in each case is

$$(x-1)\;,\;\;(x-1)^2\;,\;\;(x-1)^2\;,\;\;(x-1)^3\;,\;\;(x-1)^4$$

Cases $\;2-3\;$ depend on whether the geometry multiplicity of the eigenvalue (i.e., the eigenspace's dimension) is two or one